# How can I add a release date of a podcast to the filename or file metadata?

Tags: metadata, podcasts

I use [gPodder](https://gpodder.github.io) to download podcasts.

For example, I have downloaded the podcasts for [EconTalk](http://files.libertyfund.org/econtalk/EconTalk.xml) and this is the first podcast:

[image]

gPodder tells me that this podcast was “Released” on “2006-03-16.”

How do I add this information (`yyyy-mm-dd`, "2006-03-16") to either the front of the file name or somewhere in the file’s metadata?

My goal is to do the same for all the podcasts I’ve downloaded and not just this particular one.

---

Currently, this `yyyy-mm-dd` information doesn’t seem to appear anywhere in the file's metadata:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like gPodder already has a [built-in extension](https://gpodder.github.io/docs/extensions/renameafterdownload.html) which does this. No need to download it as it's included.

1. Click **gPodder** > **Preferences**.
2. Click the **Extensions** tab.
3. Check the box next to **Rename episodes after download**.
4. Click the **Edit config** button on the bottom-right of the preferences window.
5. Check the box next to **extensions.rename_download.add_sortdate**.
6. Close remaining windows.

All future-downloaded podcast filenames should then be prefixed with "*YYYY-MM-DD* -".

Optionally, you can also enable **extensions.rename_download.add_podcast_title** to prepend the title to the filename too.

---

You could also use the following PowerShell to rename existing files:

```
#
# PrependDateToPodcasts.ps1
#
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)][string]$FeedURL,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)][string]$Directory,
  [Parameter()][switch]$DryRun = $false
)

$XML = Invoke-WebRequest $FeedURL
$Podcasts = ($XML | Select-Xml "rss/channel/item").Node

$Podcasts | ForEach-Object {
  $Filename = Split-Path $_.enclosure.url -Leaf
  $Date = [datetime](($_.pubDate -replace " [A-Z]{3}$", "") -replace "^\w{3}", "") | Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

  $FilePath = Join-Path $Directory $Filename
  $FilenameNew = "${Date} - ${Filename}"

  if (Test-Path $FilePath) {
    Write-Host "Renaming `"${Filename}`" to `"${FilenameNew}`"."
    if (!$DryRun) {
      Rename-Item $FilePath $FilenameNew
    }
  }
}
```

```
# Preview changes before actually running.
.\PrependDateToPodcasts.ps1 "http://files.libertyfund.org/econtalk/EconTalk.xml" "C:\path\to\gPodder\Downloads\EconTalk" -DryRun

# Rename for real.
.\PrependDateToPodcasts.ps1 "http://files.libertyfund.org/econtalk/EconTalk.xml" "C:\path\to\gPodder\Downloads\EconTalk"
```

Comment: Good answer! But PowerShell is primarily a Windows tool. The screenshot shows what looks to me like a Windows interface, but I would recommend double checking with the original poster regarding what OS they are on.